# How to handle multiple intents in a single activity in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, intentservice

I have Three activity classes in my android Application .
The first activity has to pass intent to the second and third activity one has to pass intent to the second.
In this case ,How can i handle two intents in the same activity .
I thought i should use the if ,else condition . But i doubt if there is some technique to handle multiple intents in a single activity?

Comment: there is no way to call second activity from both of them at the same time..!!

Comment: just call the intents the way u usually do and get the values accordingly. and check for nulls also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()`. This is your solution.

Comment: I think you meant `onActivityResult()`, no?

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple if else condition :

```
if (intent.getStringExtra("com.example.ActivityOne.intentOne") != null) {
   // do something
} else if (intent.getStringExtra("com.example.ActivityThree.intentThree") != null) {
   // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know which `Activity` issued the current `Intent` to know what `extras` to expect or to know what to do I will sometimes just use an arbitrary `String extra` and check what that is. So in sending `Activity` something like

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, NextActivtiy.class);
i.putExtra("source", "first");  // source is the string to check where it is coming from
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the receiving `Activity`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String from = intent.getStringExtra("source");
if ("first".equals(from))
{
     // do stuff if from first Activity
}
else
{
     // do other stuff
}
```

Check if extras is not null

```
 if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
    String from = intent.getStringExtra("source");
    if ("first".equals(from)){
        // do stuff if from first Activity
    }
    else {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it make sense to add a null check to the if() statement:  "if("first" != null && "first".equals(from))..."?

Comment: Also, if there are multiple Activities issuing Intents, then does "Intent intent = getIntent();" in the receiving Activity handle all of the Intents?

Comment: @AJW yes but that also depends on your scenario. If you can guarantee that it will never be null then it's obviously useless. Always better to be safe than sorry, of course.It's often also a good idea to check if `extras` is not null before trying to access them. To your second question, yes. It will handle each of them when this activity is called.

Comment: Got it.  How would you recommend to test if extras is not null?  In your answer above would it be: "if (from != null)"?  Or some other way?

Comment: Ah, got it.  Cheers!